# cat multiple files and subshell

Tags: bash, pipe, cat

Is there a single shell command that will do the following:

```
cp header page.html
markdown page.md >> page.html
cat footer >> page.html
```

(Markdown outputs to stdout by default.)

A colleague suggested

```
echo $(cat header) $(markdown page.md) $(cat footer) >> page.html
```

But apart from three subshells and two cats, which will probably win me a "useless use of cat" award, it also strips newlines - which is no good, especially in the `<pre><code>` blocks.

What I'd like is something like this (which obviously doesn't work)

```
cat header $(markdown page.md) footer > page.html
```

where I can tell cat to use the output of the subshell for one of the files to read from. Ideally without setting up any temporary files, named pipes etc.

Comment: With bash that supports [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), this could work too: `cat header <(markdown page.md) footer > page.html` Note: Unless your bash is ancient, it would support process substitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you only have a single subshell I'd use this :

```
markdown page.md | cat header - footer > page.html
```

The `-` in the `cat` params refers to stdin, which is populated by the `markdown` command.

If you had multiple subshells, I'd recommend using the solution anishane commented about, process substitution :

```
cat header <(markdown page1.md) <(markdwon page2.md) footer > page.html
```

Comment: As long as the multiple subshells were to be treated consecutively, you could also use `{ markdown page1.md; markdown page2.md; } | cat header - footer > page.html`.

Answer (score 1):

That should do:

```
(cat header;  markdown page.md;  cat footer) >   page.html
```

Comment: You can use `{ cat header; markdown page.md; cat footer; } > page.html` to avoid an unnecessary subshell.